# Cron not creating file despite the fact that it's running

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have created a cron to run every minute under my user, which looks like this:

```
* * * * * python /var/www/html/script.py
```

The script outputs a number, and creates a html file in the /var/www/html/ folder. When the Cron runs, it sends me the email with the output, which indicates that the script has run correctly. However, the html file has not updated.

The html file updates and the number is output when I run the script manually.

Is there something I need to do to give the cron permission to update files in a certain location?

Comment: Whose crontab did you put it in?

Comment: What's in the script?

Comment: Have tried both the "pi" user and root. The script basically scrapes a number from a website, outputs that number and generates a html file (which the number is part of). It's the generating/overwriting of the html file which is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when cron was running the script, I had to have the full file location in the script. When I ran it manually, the filename seemed to suffice. I fixed it by changing the filename in the script to the full location (e.g. /var/www/filename.py instead of just 'filename.py')